# Plot stops working for packet sizes greater than 128 KB (R 1.9)

Tags: redhawksdr

To reproduce the issue, launch a SigGen component.  Plot the output port using the IDE or explorer.  Change xfer_len property of the SigGen component to a value > 16000.  The plot stops working.  I am still able to snapshot data.  I am using R 1.9.0.  Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you modify the parameter `giopMaxMsgSize` in /etc/omniOrb.cfg??
You can increase default value from 2097152(2 Mbytes) to 10485760(10Mbytes).
If you work on CentOS, you couldn't have this line in omniOrb.cfg,then you can add the followed line:
`giopMaxMsgSize = 10485760`

Usually, errors like this are followed by CORBA::MARSHAL error

Answer (score 0):

In Redhawk 1.9.0 (in contrast to the 1.8 series), the IDE's plots are set to non-blocking by default. This causes the IDE to discard data that comes in more rapidly than it can be plotted. If you need to plot very large data pushes, you can change this behavior:

1. Select the plot's view menu (downward-pointing triangle near the top right corner of the plot view)
2. Select 'Adjust Plot Settings'
3. In the dialog, set blocking to true